# Variable in scoped data in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use `var` variable in scope. How can I do like this: `$scope.jsondata.var`

In this example I want to use `datePeriod` variable in `$scope.myData[index].daily` so `$scope.myData[index].datePeriod` in controller.

Note: `daily` is a json data element. It's changes daily, weekly, monthly.

```
var datePeriod = $scope.datePeriod;

$http.get("reports?type="+datePeriod).then(function(response) {
    $scope.myData = response.data;
    angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(value, index) {
        dailyData.push({
            y: $scope.myData[index].daily,
            a: $scope.myData[index].TOTAL_CIRO,
            b: $scope.myData[index].DELIVERY_TOTAL
        });
        console.log(datePeriod);
    });
```

Comment: oops! without quotes  `$scope.myData[index][datePeriod]` where `datePeriod =  daily, weekly, monthly`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this `$scope.myData[index][datePeriod]`

where `datePeriod` = `daily` or `weekly` or `monthly`